# gstreamer: gst/app/gstappsrc.h no such file or directory

Tags: gstreamer

I have installed `gstreamer1.0-plugins-base` use command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
```

but when I compile my code, it still gives me an error

> gst/app/gstappsrc.h: no such file or directory

And I even can't find the directory `/app` at the directory `/usr/include/gstremer1.0/gst`

Answer (score 8):

You will need the development header files. The package is probably named `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev` or close to that.

Comment: thank you very very much !  and I've solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need the include (headers) and link (libs) directories for `gstreamer-app-1.0`, part of the gstreamer base-plugins.

If you are using `pkg-config`, try the following command to get all the compilation flags you need:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-app-1.0
```

In case of CMake with `pkg-config`:

```
# pkg-config
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GSTREAMER REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0)
pkg_check_modules(GSTREAMER_APP REQUIRED gstreamer-app-1.0)

# including header files directories
include_directories(
  ${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${GSTREAMER_APP_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# linking library directories
link_directories(
  ${GSTREAMER_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  ${GSTREAMER_APP_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

# linking gstreamer library with target executable
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GSTREAMER_APP_LIBRARIES})
```